# How to quickly edit imported DXF files?

Tags: qgis, editing, import, dxf

We work with lots of DXF files, and it takes much time to save imported DXF file as SHP or convert them to polygons (even using batch converter) to enable "Edit" button.

Is there any way for quicker editing lots of DXF layers right after import?

And quicker way to make qgis recognize them as polygons?

Comment: You can use batch converter ogr2ogr from gdal utilities, you can simply write a script (bash/bat/powershell) to convert huge amount of dxf files.

Comment: Use the plugin: "Another DXF Importer / DXF2Shape Converter". This allows several DXFs to be imported / converted simultaneously